# Add list elements dynamically to ul element

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to add more li elements, like the first one, dynamically, i.e. by pressing a button. Here is a not working example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/danielecordano/o93ghfc9/)

```js
document.onload = init;
function init(){
  document.getElementById('add').onclick = add;
}
function add(){
  var el = document.getElementById('list');
  var node = document.createElement("li");
  var link = document.createElement("link");
  link.setAttribute('href', 'www.google.it');
  link.setAttribute('name', 'link');
  node.appendChild(link);
  el.appendChild(node);
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>
    <a href="www.google.it">link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="add">Add link</button>
```

Comment: Use `window.onload` instead of `document.onload`.. I am not sure when `document.onload` will get invoked...

Comment: Fiddle here...https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/o93ghfc9/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fixed fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/overlord_tm/jj3j356y/6/

You probably want to create an `a` element, not `link`. Also, you want to set `innerText` property, instead of `name` attribute. And as Rayon mentioned, use `window.onload`

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.onload = init;
function init(){
  document.getElementById('add').onclick = add;
}
function add(){
  var el = document.getElementById('list');
  var node = document.createElement("li");
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.setAttribute('href', 'www.google.it');
  link.innerHTML = "link";
  node.appendChild(link);
  el.appendChild(node);
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>
    <a href="www.google.it">link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="add">Add link</button>
```